# How to create bug in azure devops automatically when pipeline execution fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to create a bug automatically in azure dev-ops when there is a failure in pipeline execution?

Thanks,
Sudheer

Comment: If I put your question title on google 3 out of the first 4 results give valid options to achieve this. What did you try? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement make a sense. The below code should works.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
#The previous steps here.
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    # xxx
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    xxx
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

#Additional Steps to create bug workitems.
- task: PythonScript@0
  condition: failed()
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      #create a bug workitem for azure devops
      import json
      import requests
      
      #give the required information here.
      organization = "<Your Organization Name>"
      project = "<Your Project Name>"
      workitem_type = "Bug"
      PAT = "<Your Personal Access Token>"
      
      
      url = "https://dev.azure.com/"+organization+"/"+project+"/_apis/wit/workitems/$"+workitem_type+"?api-version=6.0"
      
      payload = json.dumps([
        {
          "op": "add",
          "path": "/fields/System.Title",
          "from": None,
          "value": "Sample task"
        }
      ])
      headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+PAT
      }
      
      response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
      
      print(response.text)
```

Comment: with above code I'm getting below error while executing python task                 
 PythonScript
Evaluating: failed()
Result: False

Comment: @Sudheer Can you share the code you are using(remove the in-private information)? Have you give the actual information?